# How to push object without filed name in mongodb with nodejs

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**This is my Schema design**

```
 mongoose.Schema({

              traffic_countries:String,
              company_details:String,
              campaigns:[{
                    _campaignid : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,   
              }],
              impressions:[{
                    country:String,
                    _campaignid :mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
              }],
              payments:[],
              budget:String                                                })
```

**What i want to do**

I want to push the object below in the payments array the code that i am using for this purpose is given below the object

```
                {
                            "id" : "PAY-52L98986JB4797714LN73QTY",
                            "intent" : "sale",
                            "state" : "created",
                            "payer" : {
                                    "payment_method" : "paypal"
                            },
                            "transactions" : [
                                    {
                                            "amount" : {
                                                    "total" : "12.00",
                                                    "currency" : "USD"
                                            },
                                            "description" : "",

                                            },
                                            "related_resources" : [ ]
                                    }
                            ],
                            "create_time" : "2018-08-24T07:48:30Z",
                            "links" : [

                                    {

                                            "rel" : "execute",
                                            "method" : "POST"
                                    }
                            ],
                            "httpStatusCode" : 201
                    }
```

**The Code I am using for this purpose**

The above object is stored in the transaction variable that i am getting from paypal api and pushing in the payments array

```
var newPayment = {
            $push:{
                payments:{
                    transaction
                }
            }
        }



        Advertiser.updateOne({_id:req.user.id},newPayment,function(err,rec){
            if(err) throw err;

        })
```

**The objects that are stored in mongodb are like**

```
payments:[                                                                  
          { transaction:{object} },                                         
          { transaction:{object} },                                         
          { transaction:{object} }                                          
]
```

**But i want to store objects like**

```
payments:[                                                                  
          {object},                                         
          {object},                                         
          {object}                                          
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time waste i found out the answer to this problem by myself i only need to remove the extra brackets in the push query

**Instead of this**

```
var newPayment = {
        $push:{
            payments:{
                transaction
            }
        }
    }
```

**I needed that**

```
var newPayment = {
        $push:{
            payments:transaction

        }
    }
```